# How do I find a reliable XPath for this html element (type is text, class is known, no id present)?

Tags: html, google-chrome, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

The element is similar to:

`<input type="text" class="information">`

There is no id for the element.
There is only one `text` type element inside the `information` class. I want to be able to enter text into this html element by using `casperjs` which works on top of `phantomjs`.

The XPath obtained from chrome developer tools is similar to:

```
//*[@id="abcid"]/div/div[1]/input
```

abcdid is the id of the div element which comprises of the text box and a few other elements. But I need a more reliable XPath. I'm not very experienced with finding XPaths so forgive me if the answer is too obvious.

Comment: Have you actually used the XPath utility of casperjs? `var x = require('casper').selectXPath; x('//*[@id="abcid"]/div/div[1]/input')`. Why not simply using a CSS selector: `input.information[type='text']`

Comment: @ArtjomB.The 'no element found' error was due to not importing the xpath utility of casperjs. I realized that soon enough but didn't update the question because I wanted a more reliable XPath so that small changes in the html wouldn't require me to change the xpath again. I guess CSS selector would be good. I'm reading them up now. Think will go that way especially if they have similar structure as in your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use XPath selectors for nearly all CasperJS functions, you need to [provide it as an object](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/selectors.html). If the selector is provided as a string it will be automatically assumed that it is a CSS selector.

You can build the XPath selector object yourself:

```
{
    type: 'xpath',
    path: '//input[@class="information"]'
}
```

or just use a XPath utility by first requiring it at the beginning of your script and then using it:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
// later ...
var text = casper.fetchText(x('//input[@class="information"]'));
```

**Regarding your selector:**

If there is only one `input` with the `information` class then you can use the XPath

```
//input[@class="information"]
```

or the CSS selector

```
input.information[type='text']
```

If the input has other classes too, the CSS selector will work as is, but the XPath selector must be changed to

```
//input[contains(@class,"information")]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one follow up question: If I want to specify more than one class and other things like text(). Can I add them all inside the square brackets? For example: `//p[contains(@class,"class1"),contains(@class,"class2"),contains(text(),"abc")]`.

Comment: Yes, but with slightly different syntax: `//p[contains(@class,"class1") and contains(@class,"class2") and contains(text(),"abc")]‌`. Keep in mind that `text()` only returns the text nodes of the current element (text directly inside `p` in this case). If you want any text regardless how deep, you can do `//p[contains(.,"abc")]‌`